# Animate displaying element on the page with CSS/SCSS

Tags: css, animation, sass

I'm wanting to animate a sequence of divs appearing on the page, one by one. I have an animation delay set up on all of them, and the animation is being applied at the correct times for each one.

But! What I want to animate is `display: block` to `display: none`, which I know isn't possible. I've tried the `visibility: hidden` + `opacity: 0` + `height` and animating those in, but that doesn't position the elements the way I want to, because they go straight to the ending position where they ultimately end up on the page once everything's in, rather than pushing each other out of the way like I would want with a display animation.

How I can get them each to start in one spot and push each other out of the way until the end of the animation without JavaScript or manually positioning?

My current SCSS code (there are 14 `text` divs to be animated in):

```
.text-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 170px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  .text {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    max-height: 0;
    align-self: flex-start;
    margin: 3px 3px 0;
    padding: 5px;
    max-width: 80%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    animation: 7s text-bubble infinite;
  }
  // ------------ animation delay
  @for $i from 1 through 14 {
    .text {
      &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
        animation-delay: $i * 1s;
      }
    }
  }
  // ------------
}
@keyframes text-bubble {
  0% {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    max-height: 0;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    max-height: 170px;  
    transform: scale(1.15);
  }
  100% {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    max-height: 170px;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

Comment: You can have them set to `display: none` and then transition the other properties after showing them

Comment: @YaakovAinspan you can't animate `display: none`

Comment: You can have them hidden with `display: none` and `opacity:0`, then change it to `display: block` and transition the `opacity`

Comment: @YaakovAinspan where would I set display: block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you factor in the `margin` and `padding` for each item as well as the `max-height`, you can get a reasonable looking animation that should accomplish what you're looking for.

```
@keyframes text-bubble {
  0% {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    max-height: 0px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  1% {
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 3px;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1.02);
  }

  100% { 
    max-height: 170px;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/MPemKa/

I should note that this will trigger a lot of layout calculations, a JavaScript FLIP approach would be more performant, but does go against the CSS-only requirement and definitely ups the complexity!

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! Had to make a couple tweaks, but this was definitely the right idea.

Answer (score 0):

you will want your animation to look like this

```
@keyframes text-bubble {
  0% {
   display: block;
   opacity: 0;
   max-height: 0;
   transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
   opacity: 1;
   max-height: 170px;  
   transform: scale(1.15);
  }
  100% {
   opacity: 1;
   max-height: 170px;
   transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

So initially have your objects display to none,

```
.text{
   display: none;
}
```

then when you start the animation set the display to block and then animate the opacity.

Comment: This isn't working, unfortunately! I tried taking out the `transform`s and the `max-height` to see if that would fix it, but it's still coming back as `display: none;`